# emacs intellisense

Tags: emacs, intellisense, cscope, cedet

I know this has been discussed a lot of times but is there any nice how-to for c/c++ intellisense in emacs? I have never been able to set up cedet properly.

Right now I am working on a maintenance project with a huuge code base and it is very difficult to manage without proper intellisense. Currently I am using vim with ctags/cscope and omnicomplete features for intellisense which works great; but I would like to get things to work with emacs.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644490/emacs-completions-or-intellisense-the-same-as-on-visual-studio

Comment: had you seen [this article](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you cannot get CEDET working, then you could use auto-complete.el combined with CTAGS or just words-in-buffer or words-in-all-buffers. For what it's worth, if you did get CEDET working, then you would have essentially exactly what you want. It works very well for me. Auto-complete, however, is totally generic and supports any number of backends being plugged into it.

See: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete