# Emacs documentation popup

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

Is it possible for Emacs to provide a short list of possible function arguments whenever you are about to call a function?

For example, if I type out this:

```
Foo(
```

I would like to see something like

```
Foo(int x)
Foo(std::string x)
Foo(int x, int y, int z = 5)
```

pop out under my `Foo(`

Currently I am using Emacs for C++ work, but would like to know about such features for other languages like the Lisps, Python, etc., as well.
Also, I am not sure what this kind of feature is called, so I would appreciate it if you could tell me that too.

Comment: The term "intellisense" comes to mind, though I believe that's a Microsoftism. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582360/emacs-intellisense has some information that might be helpful.

Comment: actually the feature you are asking for called Eldoc in Emacs. IIRC it supports lisp and python2 not sure about other languages

Comment: check out [ropemacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855378/ropemacs-usage-tutorial) for python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [GCCSense](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/). It's a tool from the author of [auto-complete-mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) and it uses gcc to find candidates for code completion as the name suggests. [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/intellisense.shtml) also provides a smart completion mechanism for C/C++ (and other languages). [This article on setting up CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) might be useful to you as well.