# Linux programming - getting started, how?

Tags: linux, development-environment

I've taken the plunge and installed Linux (Linux Mint 9 if that's important) on one of the boxes - and I'd like to start some small-time programming... but where to start.

My background:

- Mostly LOB-applications in C#/WPF
- Some XAL-basic
- A wee bit of VB/VBA and SilverLight

I would like to turn to a new programming language - but still focused on desktop applications.

What I need:

- An editor - preferably with good intellisense
- A programming languages and the resources to get started

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be happy for a little push...

EDIT:
Thanks for all the advice - I've come up with the following:

- I'll start out with Python - and use Vim for the editor

I'll definetly try out Vala and Perl later and have MonoDevelop as backup editor - and if all else fails, I'll turn to C++. I've upvoted all answers as they all helped me.

EDIT2: 
Okay - Vim was a bit too hardcore... Installed Cream on top.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644490/emacs-completions-or-intellisense-the-same-as-on-visual-studio

Comment: That's auto-completion for Emacs only, right?

Comment: that is correct.
However other editors have similar features, but being emacs user I can only recommend emacs features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how much you want to learn (from the easiest option to the hardest one):

- Just use [C# via Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) - that gives you access to most of the POSIX interfaces via Mono.UNIX, access to [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp) so you can do desktop apps, access to many linux libraries, so you can do more advanced stuff / integrate better. (you can program in [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) - it's a Sharpdevelop clone, kind of VS-ish)
- Learn [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) - it's a language compiled down to C, very similar to C# but closer to the bare minimum. It's gathers anti-MS people who wanted a response to C# IMHO. (never really used it, but apparently there's a Vala plugin for Monodevelop and the language itself is becoming more popular)
- Learn [Python](http://www.python.org/) - it's a scripting language. It's got bindings to most popular libraries (also GTK and QT) (IDE: anything that can edit text - you won't get good intellisense from a dynamic language anyways)
- Learn C++ and QT, or C and GTK - although those are very low level languages where you will spend a lot of time just getting used to the environment. (IDE: Anjuta, Kdevelop, Monodevelop with C++ plugin, Eclipse+CDT, emacs, vim, etc. - anything goes really)

If you want "something new", but don't want to spend loads of time learning a completely new environment, I'd recommend trying out Vala. If you're more curious about different styles, go for Python, which I think has a very good tutorial for new people (but not new to programming): [Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) or [Beginner's Guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide). With Python you also have an advantage of having the whole environment available in packages in any distribution, no such luck with Vala (yet).

Comment: This was the most clean-cut answer that helped me a lot in deciding where to go - and I like the idea of Vala.

Comment: I ageree it might be a good starting point for you. Just keep in mind that it's a fresh (well - 3-4 years fresh) project. Some of those lights (http://live.gnome.org/Vala/Features) were not green just a couple of months ago. Otherwise, have fun exploring it :)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the Windows world, where everything is designed to be Windows-only, I think it is quite typical to find that the rest of the world designs software to specifications, not to implementations. If you are developing in Java, then it doesn't matter what platform you intend to use, and Eclipse and NetBeans provide excellent tooling for Java on all platforms, Linux included. If you are developing in C++, then Boost and Qt provide excellent cross-platform support. If you need to go outside of Boost or Qt, then before delving into Linux-specific features, it is best to target the [Single UNIX Specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) also known as [IEEE Std. 1003.1 POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), which will ensure that your application not only runs on Linux, but also on any UNIX-compliant operating system (including Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris, and others).

As for IDEs and other editors... I think most programmers on UNIX platforms build from the commandline (using CMake, Make, scons, or some other standard build tool); however, there are plenty of IDEs with support for those that can run such tools automatically. Anjuta C++ and KDevelop are probably the easiest IDEs to use on Linux. Emacs (emacs, emacs-gtk, xemacs) and Vim (vim, gvim) provide a great deal of power and flexibility, but take a little bit more time to get used to. You might also want to consider a basic text editor such as GEdit (Gnome) or Kate (KDE); GEdit, though billed as a simple text editor, supports some more advanced coding features via a number of plugins. I don't recall whether it supports autocompletion, but it does support line numbers, automatic indenting, using spaces instead of tabs, commenting a block of code en-masse, and executing a Makefile with a shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Try [perl](http://www.perl.org/) and [python](http://www.python.org/) and see what appeals to you. Learn [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) to get around happily at the command-line. If you're feeling adventurous, give C/C++ a shot.

As for editors, this will probably spark up a holy war, but if you're using at the command line, check out [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), pick one, and lament never making friends of those in the "enemy camp." :-)

Answer (score 2):

I say Python + Emacs or gEdit (what ever suits you)

Answer (score 2):

Linux Mint is a KDE environment, right? That would make it pretty convenient for you to get started writing KDE apps in C++. The Qt toolkit which KDE is based on is widely considered to be relatively developer-friendly, which should make it easy for you to get started.

If you want to go on that route, I'd suggest downloading KDevelop, which is KDE's IDE (optimized for developing KDE programs, but it can handle several different languages). Alternatively, you could use Eclipse, which has C++ capability. You can find tutorials on how to develop KDE apps at http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials. (Unfortunately I think those are not as good as the documentation they used to have before KDE 4 came out, but it should be enough to get you started.)

**EDIT**: Come to think of it, you may want to try your hand at writing some C++ console (non-GUI) applications first, since it's probably easier to get comfortable with basic C++ before you jump into GUI programming. Given your experience, it shouldn't be too hard to pick up. Unfortunately I don't know of any particularly good resources to learn C++ with, but I'm sure that information is somewhere on this site, and KDevelop or Eclipse would work fine as an IDE for simple C++ console apps as well.

Comment: +1. With OP's background in C#, it would be simplest for him to move to C++.

Comment: Linux Mint is Gnome by default... and I chose default :)

Comment: @Goblin: That's perfectly okay. You can still install KDevelop or any other package you want on GNOME.

Comment: Hm, well I went to the website and thought it said KDE. Oh well, casablanca is right, you can still use KDevelop or anything else. It's just that KDE/Qt programs won't integrate quite so well with your existing desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Weird that nobody suggested [ALP](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), even if it is a bit outdated, it teached me a lot of things regarding the UNIX way of programming.

Answer (score -1):

First, Learning **C** is a MUST!

Perl is underused for most stuff and you'll want to learn **BASH Shell Scripting** instead.

Grock the C code of existing (stable, well-written software) example is the Linux kernel itself! Google **"[Linux LXR](http://www.google.com/?q=linux%20LXR)"**

Once you learn the basics to C (in Linux) the **manpages** are an invaluable resource. Just do `man printf` for information on writing characters to the screen, for example.

If you are talking GRAPHICAL GUI Programs, you need to learn **GTK+** or one of the many *cross-platform GUI toolkits* (e.g. wxWidgets). **Do not learn to program the X Windows System *directly* unless you are crazy.**

For text editors, I like **Komodo Edit** and **SciTE**.

Comment: There is no "do not learn" list.  Knowing how to talk directly to X, for example, has its benefits...not least of which is being able to understand why some things in GTK+/Qt/wx are the way they are.  But it's not what people use when they want to get stuff done.

Comment: Learning X is only useful for a handful of software engineers *these days*. Hardly something I would recommend a beginner spending time learning.

Comment: X is useful in that it's the basis for every GUI framework in \*nix.  I'd recommend learning it for the same reasons i'd recommend learning assembly language; knowing it basically makes you a better programmer and gives you insights into how the GUI frameworks work, even if you never use it directly.  To tell anyone "do not learn (whatever)" is advocating ignorance, and quite frankly, i find that a disturbing position.